# How to remove temp/cache files from linux Debian?

Tags: magento-1.9

Here is the snapshot for your reference and I didn't understand why my disk space killing automatically.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I did not understand on which directory is most important in my server? And also I need to remove some of them please advise me which are unwanted...

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        12G   11G  172M  99% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G   65M  2.9G   3% /run
tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
How can I remove data in "tmpfs" directory? and where should I go find out?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below command.

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
```

also will use `apt-get autoremove` it's automatic remove unused packages.

I hope it's work for you

Comment: Tried but space disk space is same.

Comment: Please review this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226681

Comment: You can use `ncdu`  program provides the graphical output in the CLI, and works perfectly on remote servers via SSH

`$ sudo apt-get install ncdu`

`$ ncdu /`

Comment: tried ncdu command but, says command not found.

Comment: Now my disks showing avail space: 435MB mine is debian version. And also how to find the list of files with the space occupaid so, that I can go and clear easily following instructions: https://www.tecmint.com/manage-linux-filenames-with-special-characters/      https://superuser.com/questions/606874/cannot-cat-file-which-has-space-in-name-in-linux

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        12G   11G  186M  99% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G   65M  2.9G   3% /run
tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

Comment: please review  1) 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/cannot-find-what-is-filling-up-disk-space-dev-vda1-is-100-full  
2) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358319/disk-usage-on-a-specific-filesystem